# I want a record of the first day of each month

Tags: django-models, django-queryset

SQL makes it easy to create certain For example, if you want to retrieve only the first of the month (not necessarily the '1st day' of the month) from the data accumulated in a daily batch for labels in a graph.

| recorded_date |
| --- |
| 2022-09-05 |
| 2022-10-03 |
| 2022-11-01 |
| 2022-12-01 |
| 2023-01-03 |

```sql
-- collect from mysql
select  min(recorded_date) recorded_date from daily_table group by DATE_FORMAT(`recorded_date`, "%Y-%m")
```

On the other hand, queryset requires that 'values' be specified before aggregation.

```py
first_days = Industry.objects\
    .values('recorded_date')\
    .annotate(ym=Func(F('recorded_date'), Value('%Y%m'), function='DATE_FORMAT', output_field=CharField()))\
    .annotate(count=Count('id'))
```

The queryset is written out as follows

```sql
SELECT 
    `vietnam_research_industry`.`recorded_date`, 
    DATE_FORMAT(`vietnam_research_industry`.`recorded_date`, '%Y%m') AS `ym`, 
    COUNT(`vietnam_research_industry`.`id`) AS `count` 
FROM `vietnam_research_industry` 
GROUP BY `vietnam_research_industry`.`recorded_date`, DATE_FORMAT(`vietnam_research_industry`.`recorded_date`, '%Y%m') 
ORDER BY NULL
```

this is failed as follows

| recorded_date | ym | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-16 | 202212 | 757 |
| 2022-12-21 | 202212 | 757 |
| 2022-12-22 | 202212 | 757 |
| 2022-12-23 | 202212 | 757 |
| 2022-12-26 | 202212 | 757 |
| 2022-12-27 | 202212 | 757 |
| 2022-12-28 | 202212 | 757 |
| 2022-12-29 | 202212 | 757 |
| 2022-12-30 | 202212 | 757 |

Is there no choice but to use 'raw' in these cases?
Currently, all dates are retrieved without duplicates with 'distinct' and handled by setdefault in the dictionary object.

thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below query for the same.

```
Industry.objects\
.annotate(month=ExtractMonth("recorded_date"), year=ExtractYear("recorded_date"), concat=Concat("month", Value("-"), "year", output_field=CharField()))\
.values('concat')\
.annotate(Min("recorded_date"))\
.values("recorded_date__min")
```

Let me know if it helps :)

Comment: thanks Himanshu Garg san
I was helped by you :)<br><br>

```<IndustryQuerySet [{'recorded_date__min': datetime.date(2020, 5, 25)}, {'recorded_date__min': datetime.date(2020, 6, 3)}, {'recorded_date__min': 
datetime.date(2020, 7, 1)}, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']>
```